# How to create a spinner button?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a spinner button without third-party libs.

This is how my spinner currently looks:

[image]

Pretty weird, I'm struggling with the calculus in the `WM_PAINT`

Minimal compilable example:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

#define SPINNER_STEPS 12
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

struct Spinner
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
    int spinnerState = 0;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    Spinner& opt = *(Spinner*)dwRefData;

    if (msg == WM_TIMER)
    {  
        // Update the spinner state
        opt.spinnerState = (opt.spinnerState + 1) % SPINNER_STEPS;
        // Redraw the button
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (msg == WM_PAINT)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        int spinnerSize = min(opt.w, opt.h) / 2;
        int spinnerX = opt.w / 2;
        int spinnerY = opt.h / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < SPINNER_STEPS; i++)
        {
            // Calculate alpha based on the spinner state
            int alpha = (i == opt.spinnerState) ? 255 : 255 * i / SPINNER_STEPS;

            // Modify the color based on the spinner state
            COLORREF color = RGB(255 * alpha / 255, 255 * alpha / 255, 255 * alpha / 255);
            HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, color);
            SelectObject(hdc, hPen);

            // Calculate the x and y coordinates based on the spinner size
            int x1 = spinnerX + cos(2 * M_PI * i / SPINNER_STEPS) * spinnerSize / 2;
            int y1 = spinnerY + sin(2 * M_PI * i / SPINNER_STEPS) * spinnerSize / 2;
            int x2 = spinnerX + cos(2 * M_PI * (i + 1) / SPINNER_STEPS) * spinnerSize / 2;
            int y2 = spinnerY + sin(2 * M_PI * (i + 1) / SPINNER_STEPS) * spinnerSize / 2;
            MoveToEx(hdc, x1, y1, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, x2, y2);

            DeleteObject(hPen);
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        DeleteObject(hdc);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}




LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (msg == WM_ERASEBKGND)
    {
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        FillRect((HDC)wParam, &rect, brush);
        DeleteObject(brush);
        return 1;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}



int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra  = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra  = 0;
    wc.hInstance   = 0;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L".";
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    int guiWidth = 200;
    int guiHeight = 150;
    RegisterClassExW(&wc);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L".", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - guiWidth) / 2, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - guiHeight) / 2, guiWidth, guiHeight, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    Spinner spinner;
    spinner.x = 30;
    spinner.y = 30;
    spinner.w = 128;
    spinner.h = 64;

    HWND button = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", 
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_NOTIFY,
                spinner.x, spinner.y, spinner.w, spinner.h, 
                hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    SetWindowSubclass(button, ButtonProc, 0, (DWORD_PTR)&spinner);
    SetTimer(button, 1, 50, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);        
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question. Are you asking for a code review?

Comment: Im asking for how to calculate the spinner lines

Comment: Inside the loop in `WM_PAINT` you want `(i + opt.spinnerState) % SPINNER_STEPS` to account for the current state of the spinner.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Or put another way, what do you want to be different?

Comment: Does that spinner animation looks correct to you?

Comment: There is no question here which is a pre-requisite for a question and answer site